# It's possible to update a portable electron app?

Tags: electron, updates, electron-builder, portable-executable, electron-updater

I'd like to update my portable Electron app, but I'm not secure if it's possible to update a portable version.
If isn't possible, there is a script that can download the new version and update the older?

The app needs to work on Windows, with electron-builder, electron-updater and with an exe, not with a package.